# Erro permission denied em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estava eu escrevendo um código para tentar se conectar na minha rede wi-fi utilizando python.
Usei o seguinte código:

```
from wi - fi
import Cell, Scheme

try:

cell = Cell.all('wlan0')

except:

  print(Exception)

passkey = 'pass'

try:

scheme = Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', 'nome da rede', cell, passkey)
scheme.save()
scheme.activate()

except:

  print(Exception)
```

Esse código recebe um erro na primeira exceção:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/sbin/iwlist'
```

Eu executei como root e na primeira exceção foi enviado outro código de erro:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sbin/iwlist':  '/sbin/iwlist'
```

Comment: Já tentou executar seu programa em modo de Administrador ?

Comment: Já sim. Digitei no termux do celular o comando "sudo python programa.py" sem as apas

Comment: instale o pacote wireless-tools

Comment: Em que isso me ajudaria???

Comment: para que exista o `iwlist` este pacote precisa estar instalado

Comment: Acabei de instalar usando o apt-get install iwlist, foi instalado, porém não funcionou

Comment: sbin, são arquivos do root, é do sistema só pode ter acesso se tiver permissão.. você usou  o user para executar o arquivo e parece que não deu muito bem, verifica se esse programa esta em sbin... ls /sbin | grep parted      . e de permissão ao arquivo executar... chmod +x programa.py    e veja o retorno dele.